# Priority queue not sorting correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, priority-queue

I am trying to code a computer scheduling system with c++. I am using an array-based priority queue.
This is the idea of the program

Each input transaction will represent a new computer repair order to be scheduled or a “service” command. A new computer repair order will be represented in three parts separated by hyphens: customer ID (variable length), computer model year (4 digits), warranty code (y or n). Each repair order will be scheduled based on priority and the order in which the repair order was received (first-come-first-served). A warranty repair order (i.e., warranty code = ‘y’) is assigned priority 1 (highest). A non-warranty repair for a computer model less than 6 years old is assigned priority 2. A non-warranty repair order for a computer model older than 5 years is assigned a priority 3 (lowest). Each repair order is placed in a priority queue and will be serviced by the next available repair technician. A transaction that contains a “service” command results in a repair order being removed from the priority queue and the customer ID being displayed on the console. A transaction containing the string “end-of-file” will signal the end of the input. Display the number of repair orders remaining in the queue when the “end-of-file” transaction is processed.

Here is the input I used:

```
anna-2019-y
james-2012-y
jill-2008-y
```

The output when I enter the "service" command is

```
service
jill-2008-y
service
anna-2019-y
service
james-2012-y
```

but the correct output should be

```
service
anna-2019-y
service
james-2012-y
service
jill-2008-y
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class heapType{
  public:
    bool empty(); 
    void service();
    void pop();
    void push(string cus);
    int remain();
    heapType();

  private:
    int C1I;
    int C2I;
    int CI;
    int done; 
    int EOL;
    int count;
    string heap[10];
    int PI;

    void swap(int I1, int I2);
};

bool heapType::empty() {
    return (count == 0);
}

int heapType::remain() {
    return count;
}

void heapType::swap(int I1, int I2) {
    string T = heap[I1];
    heap[I1] = heap[I2];
    heap[I2] = T;
}

void heapType::service() {
    if (count == 0) {
    }
    else {
        string name = heap[0];
        int pos1 = heap[0].find('-');
        int pos2 = heap[0].find('-', pos1 + 1);
        cout << "(output: " << heap[0].substr(pos2 + 1) << ")" << endl;
    }
}

heapType::heapType() {  
    EOL = 0;
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        heap[i] = "0";
}

void heapType::push(string cus){
    if (count == 10){
        cout << "Error: queue is full." << endl;
    }
    else {
        count++;
        heap[EOL] = cus;
        CI = EOL;
        EOL++;
        done = 0;
        while (!done) {
            if (CI == 0)
                done = 1;
            else {
                PI = (CI - 1) / 2;
                if (heap[PI] <= heap[CI])
                    done = 1;
                else{
                    swap(PI, CI);
                    CI = PI;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

string change(string choice){
    string newExpression;
    int p1, p2, intYear;
    string name, year, priority, warranty;
    static int seq = 1;
    string sequence;

    p1 = choice.find('-');
    p2 = choice.find('-', p1 + 1);
    name = choice.substr(0, p1);
    warranty = choice.substr(p2 + 1);
    year = choice.substr(p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1);
    intYear = atoi(year.c_str());
    if (warranty == "y")
        priority = "1";
    else if (2019 - intYear < 6)
        priority = "2";
    else
        priority = "3";
    newExpression = priority + "-" + sequence + "-" + name;
    seq++;
    return newExpression;
}

void heapType::pop() {
    if (count == 0)
        cout << "Error: queue is empty.\n";
    else {
        if (count == 1) {
            count = 0;
            EOL = 0;
            heap[0] = "0";
        }
        else {
            if (count == 2) {
                count = 1;
                EOL = 1;
                heap[0] = heap[1];
                heap[1] = "0";
            }
            else {
                count--;
                EOL--;
                heap[0] = heap[EOL];
                heap[EOL] = "0";
                done = 0;
                PI = 0;
                C1I = 1;
                C2I = 2;
                while (!done){
                    if (C2I >= EOL){
                        if (heap[PI] > heap[C1I])
                            swap(PI, C1I);
                        done = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        if((heap[PI] <= heap[C1I]) && (heap[PI] <= heap[C2I]))
                            done = 1;
                        else {
                            if (heap[C1I] < heap[C2I]) {
                                swap(PI, C1I);
                                if ((C1I * 2 + 1) >= EOL)
                                    done = 1;
                                else
                                    PI = C1I;
                            } else {
                                swap(PI, C2I);
                                if ((C2I * 2 + 1) >= EOL)
                                    done = 1;
                                else
                                    PI = C2I;
                            }
                            C1I = PI * 2 + 1;
                            C2I = PI * 2 + 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
  heapType iHeap;
  string choice, second;

  cout << "\nInput transaction(customerid-year-warrantycode)\n";
  cout << "Service(service)\n";
  cout << "Exit program(end-of-file)\n";
  cin >> choice;

  while (choice != "end-of-file"){
    if (choice == "service"){
      iHeap.service();
      iHeap.pop();
    }
    else {
      second = change(choice);
      iHeap.push(second);
    }
    cout << "\nInput transaction(customerid-year-warrantycode)\n";
    cout << "Service(service)\n";
    cout << "Exit program(end-of-file)\n";
    cin >> choice;
  }
  cout << "(output: There are " << iHeap.remain()
       << " remaining repair orders in the queue)";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to clean up the text, but it still does not make sense to me. You have "not less than 6 years old" as your second-highest priority. Seeing how 2019 is less than 6 years old, while 2008 is not, why do you say that 2019 should have a higher priority than 2008? What is meant by "service the data"? (Maybe "process the transactions"?) Also, I cannot figure out how to parse the line _"will would not service in the order the transactions was entered first come first serve"_.

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear i updated the purpose of the program up top.!! thanks

Comment: Better. However, when I ran your code, I got the desired order of anna, james, then jill. The formatting was different (`(output: anna)` vs. `anna-2019-y`), though. Did you change your code for this post and manage to fix your bug in the process?

Comment: yes i tried with other names for example the input: jim-2001-y, jake-2012-y, frank-2011-y, and james-2019-y. The output when inputting service will be frank instead of jim. its just coincidentally the output above was what i wanted but when trying other inputs it wasn't sorting correctly

Comment: The input specified in your question should demonstrate the problem by producing incorrectly sorted output. The output listed in your question should match what the code in your question produces for that input (which includes how it is formatted/presented).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `change` function, which computes the priority and then constructs a new priority expression with this line:

```
newExpression = priority + "-" + sequence + "-" + name;
```

But you never assign it a value, so likely it's `NULL`. Is your compiler issuing a warning about this? The output from this function will be a string of the form `priority--name`.

Given your sample input (from comments), I've created this table to show the expressions you'll compute:

```
jim-2001-y      1--jim
jake-2012-y     1--jake
frank-2011-y    1--frank
james-2019-y    1--james
```

They're all the same priority and you don't have a sequence number, so they're going to be sorted alphabetically.